# write Function object to bytearray in flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, byte, arrays

I have byte array, and I want to write into it a `Function` object,
like the following:

```
var func:Function = function f(event:Event):void
{
    trace('hello');
}

var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.write...???!(func);
```

please help me... im stuck with it for few days.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can write object of some class, read it from ByteArray and cast to its original type. Functions aren't written into ByteArray, only object's data. They are always in program code, not in data.